# Mathematica does not calculate absolute values of a complex number with real coefficients

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

Using code `FullSimplify[Abs[q + I*w], Element[{q, w}, Reals]]` results in

```
Abs[q + I w]
```

and not

```
Sqrt[q^2 + w^2]
```

What am I missing?

P.S. `Assuming[{q \[Element] Reals, w \[Element] Reals}, 
 Abs[q + I*w]]` does not work either.
Note: `Simplify[Abs[w]^2, Element[{q, w}, Reals]]` and `Simplify[Abs[I*q]^2, Element[{q, w}, Reals]]` work.

Comment: I can run `Series` command on `Sqrt` but not on `Abs`.

Comment: You could try `ComplexExpand`. For example `ComplexExpand[Abs[q + I w]]` produces `Sqrt[q^2 + w^2]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that what you assume to be "Simple" and what MMA assumes to be simple are two different things. Taking a look at [ComplexityFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) indicates that MMA primarily looks at "LeafCount". Applying LeafCount gives:

```
In[3]:= Abs[q + I w] // LeafCount
Out[3]= 8

In[4]:= Sqrt[q^2 + w^2] // LeafCount    
Out[4]= 11
```

So, MMA considers the `Abs` form to be better. (One can visually explore the simplicity using either TreeForm or FullForm). What we need to do is tell MMA to treat MMA as more expensive. To do this, we take the example from [ComplexityFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) and write:

```
In[7]:= f[e_] := 100 Count[e, _Abs, {0, Infinity}] + LeafCount[e]
FullSimplify[Abs[q + I w], Element[{q, w}, Reals], 
 ComplexityFunction -> f]

Out[8]= Sqrt[q^2 + w^2]
```

As requested. Basically, we are telling MMA through `f[e]` that the count of all parts of the form `Abs` should count as 100 leaves.

**EDIT:**  As mentioned by Brett, you can also make it more general, and use `_Complex` as the rule to look for:

```
In[20]:= f[e_] := 100 Count[e, _Complex, {0, Infinity}] + LeafCount[e]
FullSimplify[Abs[q + I w], Element[{q, w}, Reals], 
 ComplexityFunction -> f]

Out[21]= Sqrt[q^2 + w^2]
```

Comment: True, and is also beneficial in being more general against all complex numbers.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest using `ComplexExpand`, which tells the system that all variables are real.

```
In[28]:= Abs[q + I*w] // ComplexExpand

Out[28]= Sqrt[q^2 + w^2]
```

Answer (score 0):

These comments are not helpful. Mathematica is failing to evaluate complex numbers, as in `Abs[5+i20]` is left unchanged. The `i` is coded correctly. Making abstract observations about 'what is or is not simple' is unrelated and wrong. There is a float that should result, not some algebra. `N` and `ImportForm` do not work, either.

Comment: lowercase `i` is an undefined symbol. Put `I` and use `N` and you will get what you expect. All unrelated to this question.